How to hit query in AWS Athena using Karate
I am looking for a tutorial to query Athena using Karate. As we know, AWS provides JDBC that can be used for this action, but so far I have been unable to find a sample project that uses JDBC Athena.
Hit query to Athena using JDBC Athena in Karate

there is a DynamoDB example that should give you a starting point: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/aws/README.md - I think all AWS services have corresponding Java SDK libraries
